# Layout will not center

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one linearLayout inside another Linearlayout that fills most of the screen. When I set the gravity of the child layout to center, it only centers vertically, but does not center horizontally.

Midlayout is the child layout inside of top layout.

```
     LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(height,height);
     params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
     LayoutParams params2=new LayoutParams(MainActivity.screenWidth,MainActivity.screenHeight-height);
     params2.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;

     ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.arrange_midlayout)).setLayoutParams(params);
     ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.arrange_toplayout)).setLayoutParams(params2);
```

Comment: can you show the xml part, it can be about the height of the parent layout.., UPDATE: try setting a background color for the parent layout and see

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` only respects gravity on the opposite axis to it's orientation, e.g. if it's orientation is horizontal then it will only set the vertical gravity. You should probably use `FrameLayout` instead for the outer container.